# What are the stairs before the door called in English?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

There is a specific word that describes the stairs before the door  [like in the picture here.](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/05/da/5c/05da5cbf0e9eb09a445fcb13fd667083.jpg)

[image: picture]

Comment: No need to add *front* because in *such context*, the word [**stoop**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoop_%28architecture%29) includes it.

Comment: veranda might be an alternative to porch

Answer (score 11):

I call them "front steps".  I live in Seattle.

My grandparents from Chicago would have called them a "front stoop".

My impression is that they are called a "stoop" in areas where row houses are common in big cities.  This might be a coincidence:  [Etymonline says that this meaning of the word "stoop" is derived from Dutch.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stoop)  New York City was originally settled by the Dutch, and is at the center of the North American "areas where row houses are common in big cities."

Comment: Being from Chicago area, I have always considered the `Stoop` as being the landing, at either the top or bottom of the steps, but not the steps themselves.

Answer (score 4):

In the UK "steps" or "front steps". In the UK a 'door step' is the single step up in front of a door (possibly two) - not steps in a flight such as these. They would not be called stairs. We also do not use 'stoops' in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

Some of us would call it a "stoop" or a "front stoop," as in the third definition [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoop).  That may vary by region in the U.S., but it is said in New England, at least.

Comment: It's a big-city usage, I think. Definitely not rural New England. Spoken as a resident (at different times) of 3 N.E. states.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I grew up in Connecticut, but with a lot of New Yorkers!